# Aptana Studio 3 - Ruby Auto-complete

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, aptana3

Ive started using Aptana Studio 3 for my Ruby project. 
it has a nice auto-complete option. you can type: someObject. ,
and a list shows up with all available methods. 
however I noticed **it doesn't list the right methods**. some methods are missing, while some methods in the list do not exist at all. ie: for String, it doesn't list: chars, chomp, upcase, etc. while it lists: as_json, which isn't a String method.
and for imported libraries like Tk, it doesn't list methods at all. 
how can I configure this? I understand it has something to do with Bundles? I couldn't find a 'Ruby' bundle. I searched Aptana Studio's website, and other question here in StackOverflow and couldn't find anything.

if this program can't do that for Ruby, what other programs can I use?

Comment: @NMPK thanks. everyone seem to recommend this program, I may buy it later. but while I'm learning, I prefer a free IDE. I'm currently trying Atom, and IntelliJ's free version. the last one is said to have 'code completion' for Ruby. hopefully it means what I think it does. I also heard TextMate can auto-complete, but I'm not really looking for a text editor.

Comment: ok, forget Atom and IntelliJ. in Atom, when I create a new file, there's no option for ruby file. the offiial website doesn't offer any support/tutorial, and I couldn't find any other tutorial for it in the web. then, 'IntelliJ Idea' requires a plugin to use Ruby, and when I try to install it, I get an error: 'the plugin is not supported in this version'. so.. I'll just keep using Aptana Studio .. it already has the auto-complete, I just need to know how to configure it correctly. can someone help?

Comment: Free licence key is available for Rubymine. Instead of using Atom and IntelliJ you can directly try with Ruby Mine.